# How to Invoke a method in a dll present in the client machine ,using Object Tag in HTML?

Tags: html, vb.net, dll, registry

I created a dll(which will be on client ) which has a class written in VB with getters returning string.

I know the code to access this class in client side is by using Object tag And referring the classid in HTML
    
But for this class to be identified by my HTML it should be registered in the registry editor.

How can i Registor in the  Regsitory Editor HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>Software>Classes>CLSID so that i can invoke it using Object Tag in HTML to call the methods in the class?

Is my understanding of the solution,wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must register your DLL using the RegAsm.exe utility.

[This article](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/register-dll.html) explains details, and [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35532/C-COM-Object-for-Use-In-JavaScript-HTML-Including) gives an extensive example.

Comment: I am not allowed to use RegAsm.exe  ,but thanks for the article

Comment: But you are allowed to make changes in the registry? You could take a (more or less) clean Windows installation, and compare the registry before and after running RegAsm.exe, and try to make those entries by hand.

Comment: Thanks i got the solution,i created an installer in Visual Studio for the solution and ran the exe on the machine